# Not able to get XRay traces or Service map from java application deployed to EC2

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, aws-xray

I have enabled xray loggin and can see the UDP packets being sent logs but seeing nothing in XRay service map or traces, I observed for more than 10 minutes, and sent multiple requests for each of those I used to see the logs from my spring-boot application:

[image]

In `WebConfig.java` I have the following:

```java
    @Bean
    public Filter TracingFilter() {
        return new AWSXRayServletFilter("Scorekeep");
    }

    static {
        AWSXRayRecorderBuilder builder = AWSXRayRecorderBuilder.standard().withPlugin(new EC2Plugin()).withPlugin(new ElasticBeanstalkPlugin());

        URL ruleFile = WebConfig.class.getResource("/sampling-rules.json");
        builder.withSamplingStrategy(new LocalizedSamplingStrategy(ruleFile));

        AWSXRay.setGlobalRecorder(builder.build());

        AWSXRay.beginSegment("Scorekeep-init");

        AWSXRay.endSegment();
    }
```

I enabled xray debugs logs seeing no error but still no traces.

**UPDATE**: I added "AWSXrayWriteOnlyAccess" role to the EC2 instance still the same issue is happening.

I noticed however in the begining of the springboot's application log there were two logs:

CloudWatch Agent log configuration file not found at /opt/a                                                                                                             ws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/log-config.json. Install the CloudWatch Agent on                                                                                                              this instance to record log references in X-Ray.

and

com.amazonaws.xray.plugins.EC2Plugin plugin returned empty                                                                                                              Log References. The recorder will not reflect the logs from this plugin.

[image]

**UPDATE2**: I have installed cloudwatch agent still seeing the same message in the log:

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE3**:

I checked the "/var/log/xray/xray.log" file:

there are some failures in sending data and the success, initially I had not attached the "AWSXrayWriteOnlyAccess" role, then I attached and restarted the application, probably it's because of that, there are success logs , still nothing shows up in servicemap or traces

[image]

Here is the screenshot of servicemap , I have kept time range as 6 hours still nothing:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally after my last update and waiting for sometime when I filtered with 3 hours data and I could see the traces:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

XRay Daemon has `NoCredentialProvider` error. Please check AWS doc, configure the creds for XRay Daemon correctly.

- AWS credential config https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html
- XRay daemon uses standard AWS SDK for go v1 https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-daemon#credential-configuration

Comment: yes, I had added "AWSXrayWriteOnlyAccess" policy as updated in my answer and it worked. As can be seen in the logs following the error.